# Quais livros você recomendam para estudar sobre análise de dados no R?

Tags: r

Gostaria de estudar mais sobre análise de dados no R e gostaria de dicas de livros,grato.

Comment: Algum tópico específico sobre análise de dados?

Comment: Algo mais voltado para Ciência de Dados,um livro introdutório que também tivesse R seria muito bom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma apostila muito bom em `R` para iniciar os estudos, que é a do prof [Paulo Justiniano](http://leg.ufpr.br/~paulojus/):
http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~paulojus/embrapa/Rembrapa/

A Springer tem vários livros com final "with R", exemplo:

[An Introduction to Applied Multivariate Analysis with R](https://www.springer.com/br/book/9781441996497)

[Introduction to Probability Simulation and Gibbs Sampling with R](https://www.springer.com/br/book/9780387402734)

então, basta procurar no google "assunto tal.. with R", que ele normalmente redireciona para um livro da Springer.

Para o Data Science, esse é um livro bem conhecido:

[R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Os livros do Julian Faraway são muito bons de ler, e são básicamente sobre modelagem estatística:
http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~jjf23/

Answer (score 2):

Além do material comentado por Guilherme Parreira, recomendo o livro **Introdução à Mineração de Dados com Aplicações em R**, de Leandro Augusto Silva.

Este livro é muito bom para esta etapa, são abordas questões relacionadas a mineração de dados, modelos preditivos e RNA, todos os temas com aplicação ou discussão em R.

E, uma questão que acho extremamente relevante nesta etapa inicial, o livro é em pt-br.

Comment: Obrigado! Já estava de olho no livro do mesmo autor o: Introdução à Mineração de Dados. Conceitos Básicos, Algoritmos e Aplicações. Você sabe algo sobre esse também?

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço este livro.